# c++ call template constructor to instantiate

Tags: c++, c++11, templates, constructor, generic-programming

Give the following program,

> hello.h

```
#ifndef HELLO_
#define HELLO_

template <typename T>
class hello
{
  T _data;
public:
  hello(T t)
  : _data(t) {}
};

template <typename T>
class world : public hello<T>
{
  T _data;
public:
  world(T t)
  : hello<T>(t) {}
};

#endif
```

> main.cc

```
#include <iostream>
#include "hello.h"

using namespace std;

class Foo
{
  int _x;
public:
  Foo(int x) : _x(x) {}
};

int main()
{
  Foo f(1);
  world<Foo> w(f);

  return 0;
}
```

I compiled it with c++11 and the compiler gives the following error messages:

```
In file included from main.cc:2:0:
hello.h: In instantiation of ‘world<T>::world(T) [with T = Foo]’:
main.cc:16:22:   required from here
hello.h:19:15: error: no matching function for call to ‘Foo::Foo()’
   : hello<T>(t) {}
               ^
main.cc:10:3: note: candidate: Foo::Foo(int)
   Foo(int x) : _x(x) {}
   ^
main.cc:10:3: note:   candidate expects 1 argument, 0 provided
main.cc:6:7: note: candidate: constexpr Foo::Foo(const Foo&)
 class Foo
       ^
main.cc:6:7: note:   candidate expects 1 argument, 0 provided
main.cc:6:7: note: candidate: constexpr Foo::Foo(Foo&&)
main.cc:6:7: note:   candidate expects 1 argument, 0 provided
```

There must be something I missed in the template definition, but I am not sure where it is. For primitive types such as `int` or `double`, it works. It does not work with class I defined, e.g. `Foo`.

Comment: @user1438832 `world<Foo> w();` is pretty valid C++ code

Comment: Sorry,Yes its valid but the intention is to pass the foo object.

Comment: @user1438832 @Danh sorry guys, I made the typo. though it is valid, the `world<Foo> w(f)` is not the cause. Dahn is correct that I shouldn't put the T again in the child class.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In `world<T>`

```
template <typename T>
class world : public hello<T>
{
  T _data;
public:
  world(T t)
  : hello<T>(t) {}
};
```

Because `T` in this case (`Foo`) is not default-constructible. I guess this is mistaken added because there is another `T _data;` in `hello<T>`. Remove it, and your code should work well. Like this:

```
template <typename T>
class world : public hello<T>
{
public:
  world(T t)
  : hello<T>(t) {}
};
```

[Demo](http://melpon.org/wandbox/permlink/dVy2aqqnq2UFTlL1)

---

Not related to the error you asked, in your main:

```
world<Foo> w();
```

This declares `w` as a function with no parameters and return `world<Foo>`.

I guess it's not what you want (forgive me if I were wrong). I guess this is what you want:

```
world<Foo> w(f);
```

or

```
world<Foo> w{f};
```

Answer (score 0):

Private data from the parent class are encapsulated and they do exist. Repeatedly define the data with the same variable name in the children class would incur such error, regardless it's about template class or just normal class.